# Function in R that uses multiple data sources

Tags: r, function

I have number of different tables and I want to write a function in R in which:

Table No.1:

```
          coordinates var1.pred  var1.var observed    residual      zscore fold
1  (2579410, 1079720)  5.057024 0.4325275    5.468  0.41097625  0.62489903    1
2  (2579330, 1079730)  5.329797 0.3945041    4.498 -0.83179667 -1.32431534    2
3  (2579260, 1079770)  4.788211 0.5576228    5.114  0.32578861  0.43628035    3
4  (2579930, 1080030)  5.067753 0.4972365    4.764 -0.30375347 -0.43076434    4
5  (2579700, 1079770)  5.116632 0.5792768    4.626 -0.49063190 -0.64463327    5
6  (2579540, 1079640)  4.865667 0.6122453    6.522  1.65633254  2.11682434    6
7  (2579860, 1079880)  5.139779 0.4655840    4.856 -0.28377887 -0.41589245    7
```

if the value of 'observed' lay ouside the tolerance of two folllowing values label it as outlier:

```
var1.pred+(1.96*sqrt(var1.var))
var1.pred-(.96*sqrt(var1.var))
```

in other words:

```
      if   
   var1.pred-(1.96*sqrt(var1.var)) < 'observed' <  var1.pred-(1.96*sqrt(var1.var))
```

results normal otherwise results outlier.

Moreover, names of the columns are the same and table names are 1,2,3 .... .

```
 dat <- structure(list(coordinates = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L,                                
     4L, 6L), .Label = c("(2579260, 1079770)", "(2579330, 1079730)",                                
     "(2579410, 1079720)", "(2579540, 1079640)", "(2579700, 1079770)",                              
     "(2579860, 1079880)", "(2579930, 1080030)"), class = "factor"),                                
         var1.pred = c(5.057024, 5.329797, 4.788211, 5.067753, 5.116632,                            
         4.865667, 5.139779), var1.var = c(0.4325275, 0.3945041, 0.5576228,                         
         0.4972365, 0.5792768, 0.6122453, 0.465584), observed = c(5.468,                            
         4.498, 5.114, 4.764, 4.626, 6.522, 4.856), residual = c(0.41097625,                        
         -0.83179667, 0.32578861, -0.30375347, -0.4906319, 1.65633254,                              
         -0.28377887), zscore = c(0.62489903, -1.32431534, 0.43628035,                              
         -0.43076434, -0.64463327, 2.11682434, -0.41589245), fold = 1:7), .Names = c("coordinates", 
     "var1.pred", "var1.var", "observed", "residual", "zscore", "fold"                              
     ), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Might you mean `1.96 * sqrt(var1.var)`?

Comment: should be `var1.pred-(.95*var1.var)  < 'observed' <  var1.pred +(.95*var1.var)`

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, why do u think so?

Comment: 1.96 times the standard error is often used as an estimate of the 95% confidence interval. You than see if the observation is outside that confidence interval...but if you have good reasons to otherwise.

Comment: can you give give dput(table1) ... just so that we can replicate the data

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra, Yes you are right, I made mistake. do u have any refrence for it that i can refer to that.

Comment: You could for example take a look at a paper I wrote in Computer and Geosciences (http://www.numbertheory.nl/files/PHiemstra_CandG_paper.pdf). Sorry for the self promotion ;). The relevant bit is at the end of section 4.1.

Comment: Btw, the `automap` package (which I authored, again self promotion) has a function called `compare.cv`, it calculates a number of statistics based on the cross-validation results you show above. It also provides a means of plotting the cross-validation residuals spatially: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/automap/docs/compare.cv.

Comment: @HamedFootohi   just minor typo in your question still.. the right most expression after "in other words" should have +ve sign

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, Thanks for your help. I want to detect outliers in my dataset, so I have performed the spatial predictions to see where predictions and observations are different. So, I think by using confidence interval i can do this. What is your idea? And is 95% is appropate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
dat$outlier = with(as.data.frame(dat), 
                   ifelse(observed > (var1.pred + (.95*var1.var)) | # | = OR
                          observed < (var1.pred - (.95*var1.var)),
             "outlier", "normal"))
```

My code is a bit different from your description, as I check if the value is outside the range, not if it is inside. The above run on your example code:

```
> dat
         coordinates var1.pred  var1.var observed   residual     zscore fold
1 (2579410, 1079720)  5.057024 0.4325275    5.468  0.4109762  0.6248990    1
2 (2579330, 1079730)  5.329797 0.3945041    4.498 -0.8317967 -1.3243153    2
3 (2579260, 1079770)  4.788211 0.5576228    5.114  0.3257886  0.4362803    3
4 (2579930, 1080030)  5.067753 0.4972365    4.764 -0.3037535 -0.4307643    4
5 (2579700, 1079770)  5.116632 0.5792768    4.626 -0.4906319 -0.6446333    5
6 (2579540, 1079640)  4.865667 0.6122453    6.522  1.6563325  2.1168243    6
7 (2579860, 1079880)  5.139779 0.4655840    4.856 -0.2837789 -0.4158925    7
  outlier
1 outlier                                                                   
2 outlier                                                                   
3  normal                                                                   
4  normal                                                                   
5  normal                                                                   
6 outlier                                                                   
7  normal
```

Answer (score 5):

Paul's answer is all good, just slightly different suggestion.

```
> dat
         coordinates var1.pred  var1.var observed   residual     zscore fold
1 (2579410, 1079720)  5.057024 0.4325275    5.468  0.4109762  0.6248990    1
2 (2579330, 1079730)  5.329797 0.3945041    4.498 -0.8317967 -1.3243153    2
3 (2579260, 1079770)  4.788211 0.5576228    5.114  0.3257886  0.4362803    3
4 (2579930, 1080030)  5.067753 0.4972365    4.764 -0.3037535 -0.4307643    4
5 (2579700, 1079770)  5.116632 0.5792768    4.626 -0.4906319 -0.6446333    5
6 (2579540, 1079640)  4.865667 0.6122453    6.522  1.6563325  2.1168243    6
7 (2579860, 1079880)  5.139779 0.4655840    4.856 -0.2837789 -0.4158925    7

> dat$label <- ifelse(dat$observed < dat$var1.pred-(1.96*sqrt(dat$var1.var)) |  dat$observed > dat$var1.pred+(1.96*sqrt(dat$var1.var)), "outlier", "normal" )

> dat
         coordinates var1.pred  var1.var observed   residual     zscore fold   label
1 (2579410, 1079720)  5.057024 0.4325275    5.468  0.4109762  0.6248990    1  normal
2 (2579330, 1079730)  5.329797 0.3945041    4.498 -0.8317967 -1.3243153    2  normal
3 (2579260, 1079770)  4.788211 0.5576228    5.114  0.3257886  0.4362803    3  normal
4 (2579930, 1080030)  5.067753 0.4972365    4.764 -0.3037535 -0.4307643    4  normal
5 (2579700, 1079770)  5.116632 0.5792768    4.626 -0.4906319 -0.6446333    5  normal
6 (2579540, 1079640)  4.865667 0.6122453    6.522  1.6563325  2.1168243    6 outlier
7 (2579860, 1079880)  5.139779 0.4655840    4.856 -0.2837789 -0.4158925    7  normal
```

update : by the way if you are looking for function which does this, and as you mention that column names are always same, you can write the function as

```
checkRange <- function(dat) {
  dat$label <- ifelse(dat$observed < dat$var1.pred-(1.96*sqrt(dat$var1.var)) |  dat$observed   dat$var1.pred+(1.96*sqrt(dat$var1.var)), "outlier", "normal" )
  return(dat)
}
> dat <- checkRange(dat)

> dat
         coordinates var1.pred  var1.var observed   residual     zscore fold   label
1 (2579410, 1079720)  5.057024 0.4325275    5.468  0.4109762  0.6248990    1  normal
2 (2579330, 1079730)  5.329797 0.3945041    4.498 -0.8317967 -1.3243153    2  normal
3 (2579260, 1079770)  4.788211 0.5576228    5.114  0.3257886  0.4362803    3  normal
4 (2579930, 1080030)  5.067753 0.4972365    4.764 -0.3037535 -0.4307643    4  normal
5 (2579700, 1079770)  5.116632 0.5792768    4.626 -0.4906319 -0.6446333    5  normal
6 (2579540, 1079640)  4.865667 0.6122453    6.522  1.6563325  2.1168243    6 outlier
7 (2579860, 1079880)  5.139779 0.4655840    4.856 -0.2837789 -0.4158925    7  normal
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer.  For some reason, I had forgotten a data frame could be amended this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is good news for you Hamed.  Packages already exists that makes work like this incredibly easy.  My personal favorite for this sort of work is the 'plyr' package.  To add a [tolerances] column to your data frame, you would use the 'ddply' function (input is a data frame and output is a data frame, hence the 'dd' prefix for the 'ply').

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(fold), mutate, tolerances=ifelse(observed < (var1.pred - 0.95 * var1.var)|observed > (var1.pred + 0.95 * var1.var),"Outlier","Normal"))
```

I'll explain each of these function arguments for posterity, and so you can adjust them to your needs.  We are telling 'ddply' to load the data from the data frame [dat], and we are using the column [fold] as the primary key.  We have to tell 'ddply' what to use as a key, because it automatically tries to aggregate data that fits the key.  Using [fold] ensures that we get a result for every line.  Next, we are using the 'mutate' function, which preserves all of the original data but adds new columns that we specify.  Finally, we are specifying a new column [tolerances] which has an 'ifelse' statement checking if the [observed] value is less than the lower tolerance or higher than the upper tolerance.  If true, the value is "Outlier" and if false, the value is "Normal".

Comment: No need to use `ddply` for this, you can directly operate on the vectors without looping with `ddply`. This makes your suggestion overly complicated...